# What's the correct: bread with cheese or bread and cheese?

Tags: word-choice

When you want to put them together, should you say "bread and" or "bread with"? Do North American use "with" and "and" inverted in this case?

Comment: It's six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: This needs context. Please give example sentences.

Comment: Certainly in the UK the standard expression is _bread and butter, bread and jam, bread and cheese_ etc.

Comment: Indeed , that is the Conclusion I get from "google ngram viewer" , @KateBunting , though Statistics is not everything.

Comment: If you're discussing different ways to serve bread: "I like my bread with cheese but he likes his bread with peanut butter". If it's your shopping list "bread and cheese". Other contexts will vary.

Comment: No, it can be: We had butter with bread, not cheese. We had cheese with bread, not butter. And yes to Stuart F, as well. And this has zero to do with BrE or AmE. It is just English. But: We love bread and butter (both AmE and BrE).

Comment: I'm talking about the common way of referring to common combinations. A plate of slices of bread spread with butter is always 'bread and butter', not 'bread with butter'.

Comment: @KateBunting Sure, of course, but the words bread and butter are not always used like that. They can be used in ways other than pairing them. And when paired, they are paired the exact same way in American English.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit of a home baker, and British. To me, something accompanying bread would *generally* use "and". So "bread and cheese", "bread and jam", and definitely "bread and butter", which are all toppings. As an appetiser, a menu might have "bread and olives", which could be served separately.

Bread "with" something, to me, is more likely to mean the something is an enhancement that's part of the bread, and would have a further preposition: I make "bread with seeds in" or occasionally "bread with cheese [baked] on top" (also called a "cheese topped loaf").  But "with" could be used in something like "lunch will be bread with cold meats and cheeses"; the use of "and" in the list of foods forming the rest of the meal makes "with" helpful in such a construction where an item is followed by a list of others, rather than being a member of that list.

If bread itself is the accompaniment to a meal, "with bread" would be normal ("with bread and butter" in some cases).

Comment: Bread and butter as a pair is the same in AmE. But those words are not always paired. They can occur in other forms in English.

Comment: @Lambie - I don't think either Chris or I were suggesting that they couldn't - just that _bread and ..._ is the most usual.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, fine. It is also the **most usual** in AmE.

Answer (score -1):

According to "google ngram viewer" , the [Usage Data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22bread%20and%20butter%22%2C%22bread%20and%20cheese%22%2C%22bread%20and%20jam%22%2C%22bread%20with%20butter%22%2C%22bread%20with%20cheese%22%2C%22bread%20with%20jam%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is that everybody is using "and" & almost nobody uses "with" , even when considering "bread" combined with "cheese" or "butter" or "jam" , in general.

The Image shows that "and" is used almost exclusively , while "with" is not even visible on the Image.

[image: BREAD COMBINATIONS]

This trend in common to US & British English.

Culinary Observation : jam is not "common" , while butter is the "standard" , with cheese taking the "middle spot".

Comment: This data is not helpful without more context. It simply tells us that these two words show up more frequently in a coordination than they do with one as dependent of the other - not really surprising. Try an ngram of 'garlic bread * cheese' and you'll get quite a different result. The point of the question, I believe, was when they are combined or paired, as in a sandwich or on a platter.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean , @DW256 , this is what I got [[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4Mep.png ]] where "asterisk" is not working for me , though "with" still has no match & "and" is available !

Comment: Like [this](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=garlic+bread+*+cheese&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3#).

Comment: Oh , I got that now , thank you , @DW256 , Ok I see that "garlic" list Percentages are 100 times less than my list Percentages & are not "Statistically Significant" , what-ever that means ! More-over , these are showing up recently : My guess is that these are the Pizza Shop Items , where Customers might want Pizza/Bread with Cheese/Sauce. In that Case , "with" is always used , where "and" is for multiple items. Eg "I want a large Pizza **with** vegetable toppings **and** garlic bread **with** cheese" : here "with" & "and" will not get mixed up. Else-where , "and" seems 100 times more common !

Comment: That's just my point - it really depends on what the OP meant by 'put them together': appearing next to one another in the language in general (_Remember to buy some milk, bread and/with cheese!_), or as in parts of a single food item (_Ooh, this bread and/with cheese looks yummy!_). Of course _and_ will be far more common in the former.

Comment: Ah , Yes , OP has to give more Context , limiting the "Usage Situation" , @DW256 , otherwise , this answer is very much general in nature.

Comment: Ngram is not useful here.